# java.io.tmpdir when running java_test with bazel

Tags: java, scala, continuous-integration, bazel

### motivation:

I have a test that needs to write a **short** temp file (must be < 107 characters).
Currently the test is using

```
Files.createTempFile(null,".sock");
```

---

### issue

which when running
I'm trying to figure out the `java.io.tmp` value when running java test using **bazel**. The different options I have is:

- Setting `$TEST_TMPDIR` (or without)
- Using `"local"=True` (or without)

Here is the result:

```
# local=True + TEST_TMPDIR=/btmp:
/btmp/_bazel_ors/719f891d5db9fd5e73ade25b0c847fd1/execroot/__main__/_tmp/8be6e61521c57d3cfc8585efa880e1ac/1638063256753562848.sock

# local=False + TEST_TMPDIR=/btmp:
/btmp/_bazel_ors/719f891d5db9fd5e73ade25b0c847fd1/bazel-sandbox/5561433121200492142/execroot/__main__/_tmp/8be6e61521c57d3cfc8585efa880e1ac/4867903879018296623.sock

# local=True , no TEST_TMPDIR:
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ors/719f891d5db9fd5e73ade25b0c847fd1/execroot/__main__/_tmp/8be6e61521c57d3cfc8585efa880e1ac/984443110479498941.sock

# local=False , no TEST_TMPDIR:
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ors/719f891d5db9fd5e73ade25b0c847fd1/bazel-sandbox/6199384508952843116/execroot/__main__/_tmp/8be6e61521c57d3cfc8585efa880e1ac/4588114364301475150.sock
```

Seems like the shortest temp prefix I can get is:

```
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_ors/719f891d5db9fd5e73ade25b0c847fd1/execroot/__main__/_tmp/
```

which is **85** char long (way too long for my needs).

**How can I safely play with this configuration and make it a lot shorter?**

---

#### note:

My env is **mac osx sierra** and I'm running bazel `0.5.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solvable by adding this to the `jvm_flags` of the test target:

```
"jvm_flags" = ["-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp"],
```

But note that it would make the test less hermetic

Answer (score 1):

You can also tell bazel where it should store its outputs `--output_base=/tmp/foo`.